# Displaying alert dialog box in all the screens

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am developing an application which will display an Alertdialog box when it gets an event.
Currently the alert will come only in that particular activity.
I need to get this alert on all the screens ( eg. home screen, message screen, etc )except I am in a call.

Please provide a solution for this.

Comment: Please elaborate your question more !

Comment: I want to display a pop up (alert dialog) when I receive a particular event (when i get an sms). The pop up should be displayed on all the screens i.e. Screens other than my application screens.

Answer (score 2):

Create some `Utils` class with static method that will takes `Context` as an argument and builds whole dialog.

Edit:

```
public class Utils {

    public static AlertDialog getDialog(Context context) {

        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        return builder
            .setTitle("title")
            .create()
            ;

    }

}
```

And call it in every place you need:

```
Utils.getDialog(context).show();
```

Comment: Also either in Application Class or in Base Activity which all Activity extends..

Comment: Can you please explain me how to do this. I am pretty new to android

Comment: user370305, I don't think you can do it in application class

Answer (score 1):

You can create a AlartMessage.java file in util package where put this static method.

```
public static void showMessage(final Context c, final String title,
        final String s) {
    final AlertDialog.Builder aBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);
    aBuilder.setTitle(title);
    // aBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
    aBuilder.setMessage(s);

    aBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

    });

    aBuilder.show();
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am new to android. Can you please tell me where is the util package.

Comment: you can create a util package (com.your_project_name.util) in your application,where you put the AlartMessage.java file then you call the  showMessage method from any activity and pass proper parameter to display message dialog.

Comment: Hi, I used the way you suggested. But it is showing the popup only in that activity screen. I am not getting that pop up in other screens. I should get that in all screens like home screen, messages screen etc...

Comment: You have to call this method from all Activity where you want to show pop up.

Comment: How is it possible bro. I need to show in all the screens. I dont have the codes of all those.

Answer (score 1):

In `Utils` class, make this method :

```
public static AlertDialog showAlertWithListeners(Context context, String title, String message, String textPositive,
                                          String textNegative,
                                          DialogInterface.OnClickListener positiveButtonClickListener,
                                          DialogInterface.OnClickListener negativeButtonClickListener) {
    if (textNegative != null)
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton(textPositive, positiveButtonClickListener)
                .setNegativeButton(textPositive, negativeButtonClickListener)
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .show();
    else
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton(textPositive, positiveButtonClickListener)
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .show();

}
```

For example, in class in which you need to show alert :

```
DialogInterface.OnClickListener positiveButtonClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            startActivity(new Intent(context, SignInActivity.class));
                                            SignUpActivity.this.finish();
                                        }
                                    };
AlertDialog successDialog = Utils.showAlertWithListeners(context, getResources().getString(R.string.success),
                                            signUpDetailResponse.message, getResources().getString(R.string.ok), null,
                                            positiveButtonClickListener, null);
successDialog.show();
```

Comment: Best solution among all the available ones in SO! Really appreciate it,

Answer (score 0):

Create one class and make one constructor in it . Pass the Activity context to constructor. Now make one function and put code of Alert Dialog in it.

Now whenever you want that dialog you can just call it with crate object of that class and call function of alert Dialog.