# Creating an Alert Dialog that should display in every screen of my Android app

Tags: android, dialog, broadcastreceiver

Is it possible to create a custom alert dialog which should be displayed when a broadcast receiver receives in any of the screens, like home screen, launcher screen etc.

Comment: Why `Dialog` and not i.e. `Toast`? The latter would popup everywhere w/o much hassle

Comment: You can see this post hope help you:
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12209777/displaying-alert-dialog-box-in-all-the-screens/12209930#12209930

Comment: Use notifications instead ...

Answer (score 0):

Create On activity Called BaseActivity

```
public BaseActivity extends Activity
{
    onCreate()
    {}//...

   // Create One Function with title and message arguments 
   public showmessage(String title,String message)
   {
    // Alert Dialog code
   }

}
```

Then in your multiple activities

```
public Activity1 extends BaseActivity
{
    onCreate()
    {

     // You can call directly 
      showmessage("Title","messsage");

    }

}

public Activity2 extends BaseActivity
{
    onCreate()
    {

      // You can call directly 
      showmessage("Title","messsage");

    }

}
```